# Codility - Frogjmp - Needs improvement

Tags: java

I was trying to write a code for Frogjmp from Codility.
I tried this solution and couple others, I can not get 100%. (other answers produced lower scores)

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        int diff = Y - X;
        int steps = 0;
        if( D != 0){
            if((diff % D) == 0)
                steps = diff %  D;
            else
                steps = diff / D + 1;
        }
        return steps;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what exactly is going wrong in here.

Thank you.

This is my first time asking for help here, so forgive me if I am making mistake on title or anything.

Comment: D is non-zero by definition, no need to check that.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if( D != 0){
        if((diff % D) == 0)
            steps = diff %  D; // this should be steps = diff / D;
                               // since you don't want to assign 0 to steps
        else
            steps = diff / D + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more elegant solution for this frogJump code. It showed 100% in codility.

```
    int distanceToJump = Y-X;
    //not a valid distance to jump
    if(distanceToJump <= 0){
        return 0;
    }else if(distanceToJump % D > 0){
        return (distanceToJump / D)+1;
    }else{
        return distanceToJump/D;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
public int solution(int X, int Y, int D) {
    return (int) Math.ceil(((double) Y - X) / D);
}
```

https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingZHDKSS-96K/

Answer (score 0):

The assumptions state that X ≤ Y, [this solution](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingEQYCHU-GB7/) shows 100% in codility:

```
function solution(X, Y, D) {
    // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 6.4.0)
    return Math.ceil((Y - X) / D);
}
```